# PostgreSQL Index Not Utilized for JSONB Field Filtering on Non-Equality: What Am I Missing?

Tags: postgresql, sql-execution-plan, postgresql-12, query-planner, partial-index

I have a table in my database called "mytable," which contains a "date" field with JSONB data like this:

```
{
  ...
  "myfield": "value1"
}
```

The "myfield" field can currently have values "value1," "value2," and "value3." Additionally, "myfield" can be null, or it might not exist at all.

In my queries, I need to find rows where "myfield" is not equal to "value1."

```sql
select * from mytable where data->>'myfield' <> 'value1'
```

I've created a partial index on the "mytable" table to speed up the query:

```sql
CREATE INDEX "idx_mytable_myfield" ON "mytable" USING btree (
  ((data->>'myfield'::text) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default" "pg_catalog"."text_ops" ASC NULLS LAST
) WHERE 
  (data->>'myfield'::text)::text <> 'value1'::text
)
```

However, the query is not using this index. At the same time, the selectivity of the query is high, and a sequential scan is significantly slower.

If I rewrite the query and index to use "in" instead of "<>", the index is used in the query. But this means I'll have to rewrite both the query and the index when adding new values in the future:

```sql
select * from mytable where (data->>'myfield'::text)::text in ('value2'::text,'value3'::text)
```

Can you please help me understand what I'm doing wrong? Is there a way to rewrite the query and/or the index?

---

To address possible questions in advance:

1. I've run `ANALYZE mytable` after each index change.
2. The query has high selectivity.
3. ChatGPT asked about this and suggested exactly what I'm trying to do.
4. My PostgreSQL version is 12.14.
5. I don't want to build not partial index on data->>'myfield' or GIN index on all data field because of perfomance and index size

P.S.
I've tried adding additional conditions to both the index and the query, but it didn't help:

```sql
...
and data is not null
and data->'myfield'::text is not null
```

```sql
CREATE INDEX "mytable_myfield_idx" ON "set10"."mytable" USING btree (
  ("data" ->> 'myfield'::text)  COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default" "pg_catalog"."text_ops" ASC NULLS LAST
)
WHERE ("data" ->> 'myfield'::text <> 'нет');
```

```sql
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, VERBOSE, COSTS)
SELECT  
    *
FROM
    mytable
WHERE
    "data" ->> 'myfield'::text <> 'нет'
```

```
Seq Scan on set10.mytable  (cost=0.00..2041.22 rows=86911 width=35) (actual time=19.098..35.258 rows=74 loops=1)
  Output: "jiraKey", data, created
  Filter: ((mytable.data ->> 'myfield'::text) <> 'нет'::text)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 87274
  Buffers: shared hit=731
Planning Time: 0.051 ms
Execution Time: 35.278 ms
```

And my experiments show that the problem is in "<>", the optimizer won't use the index in this case.

**upd**

if I force to disable seqscan - the optimizer uses my index properly. For the some reason, it thinks that it is better to use seqscan, but it wrong

```sql
SET enable_seqscan = false;
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS, COSTS, VERBOSE)
select 
    *
FROM    
    mytable
WHERE
    "data"->>'myfield' <> 'нет'
```

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on set10.mytable  (cost=30.20..2064.86 rows=86911 width=35) (actual time=0.024..0.098 rows=74 loops=1)
  Output: "jiraKey", data, created
  Recheck Cond: ((mytable.data ->> 'myfield'::text) <> 'нет'::text)
  Heap Blocks: exact=52
  Buffers: shared hit=53
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on mytable_myfield_idx  (cost=0.00..8.47 rows=86911 width=0) (actual time=0.013..0.014 rows=74 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=1
Planning Time: 0.059 ms
Execution Time: 0.128 ms
```

Comment: Could you please share the result from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers)` for this statement? All in plain text. By the way, `data->>'myfield'::text` and `data->'myfield'::text` is not the same, and could be the reason the index can't be used.

Comment: Is the index used if you don't make it partial? My guess is that you'll need to change the statistics taken on the table (for the index)

Comment: @FrankHeikens
"By the way, data->>'myfield'::text and data->'myfield'::text is not the same, and could be the reason the index can't be used"

Thanks! I've fixed my post. I mean "data->>'myfield'::text" everywhere.

I've added EXPLAIN in my original question

Comment: @Bergi
> Is the index used if you don't make it partial? 
No

> My guess is that you'll need to change the statistics taken on the table (for the index)
I've done it with ANALYZE. Or you mean something else?

Comment: You don't have an index that supports your query. Try a different query 'WHERE "data" ->> 'myfield'::text <> 'нет'' AND "data" ->> 'myfield'::text ='something';`

Comment: @FrankHeikens sure, it will work cause, the same as my example "in ('value2'::text,'value3'::text)". But. it requires use the concrete values, and I don't want to because my goal is to fetch all records, where value any but "value1". In my point of view, when I create index with condition "data"->>'myfield' <> 'нет', optimizer have to  use this index to find all records, covered this index. And if I use enable_seqscan=off, optimizer uses my index (have added to my original post).

Answer (score 1):

In order to let it get an accurate estimate of the row counts, you need an expression index like this:

```
create index on mytable ((data->>'myfield'));
```

And then do an ANALYZE after it is created.  You already have that expression index in a partial form, but partial indexes are not used by the planner to derive rows counts.

If you were using a modern version of the software, you could instead create extended statistics on the expression:

```
create statistics asldfj on (data->>'myfield') from mytable;
```

This will generate the same statistics as the index does, but doesn't have the same storage or maintenance needs as the index.  But it requires v14 or above.